# how can i turn my react webapp into a chrome desktop app? just like youtube music

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

how can i turn my react webapp into a chrome desktop app? just like youtube music.

I noticed today that youtube music suggests to "download" the app. Once clicked the app can be used like a regular desktop app. It seems however that it is just running chrome in the background disabling menus.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use electron for that - https://www.electronjs.org/
Not only React app can be converted to a desctop app, but any JS application.